# Why is slick slider not unfiltering class?

Tags: javascript, slick.js

My slickFilter works just fine, but slickUnfilter not working?

MY HTML:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper" id="wrapper">
      <div class="post" id="post1"></div>
      <div class="" id="post2"></div>
      <div class="" id="post3"></div>
      <div class="" id="post4"></div>
</div>
```

My code:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.slider-wrapper').slick('slickFilter', '.post'); 
},10000);

setInterval(function(){
    $('.slider-wrapper').slick('slickUnfilter');
},12000);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ajtwz3Lv/8/
For some reason JS fiddle is working, but my local HTML file does not.

Comment: `<div class=".post" id="post1"></div>` must be `<div class="post" id="post1"></div>` (class post without dot) 
Slick filter working with jQuery `.filter()` You can check more examples on this [link](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: Oh sorry, my local HTML file does not contain a dot. I don't know how it got here. I have updated my question. But my filter is working as it should, I don't see the reason for slickUnfilter to not work. There documentation sais it should. @Greg--

Comment: Can you create a snippet or codepan demo?

Comment: I have added JSFiddle to my question, on JSFiddle everything is working I don't know why. @Greg--

Comment: im don't know how to use JSFiddle (how to fork), so i create [Codepan](https://codepen.io/-greg-/pen/GRZEgrW?editors=1111) demo

Comment: Codepan example workig good, check you local file

Comment: Are you including your `setInterval()` functions within your  `$(document).ready()` in your local code? They are not set up this way in your JSFiddle, but that site might add one implicitly to the code in the JS window.

Comment: It turns out that this was the problem. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSFiddle, you do not appear to be including the `setInterval()` functions within your `$(document).ready()`. If you're not doing this in your local code, the `slider-wrapper` may not be initialized by Slick before you attempt to add the  `setInterval()`.

Often sites like JSFiddle will wrap all of the JS code in a `$(document).ready()`, which would explain why it's working there.